# ValueError while trying to run the Sequential Model from Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, valueerror

I'm trying to build a NARX NN with Keras. I'm still not 100% sure on the use of the argument **return_sequence=True** in the LSTM neurons but, before I can check that, I need to make the code work. When I try to run it I get the following message:

`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_84_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (6686, 3)`

See my code below. The error is raised while running the **model.fit** command. My data data is of the shape 40101 time steps x 6 features (3 exogenous inputs, 3 system responses).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import initializers

# --- main
data = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx',usecols=['wave','wind','current','X','Y','RZ'])
data.plot(subplots=True, figsize=[15,10])

x_data = np.array(data.loc[:,['wave','wind','current']])
y_data = np.array(data.loc[:,['X','Y','RZ']])

timeSeriesCrossValidation = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5)
for train, validation in timeSeriesCrossValidation.split(x_data, y_data):  

    # create model
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    
    # input layer
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=50,
                                   input_shape=(40101,3),
                                   dropout=0.01,
                                   recurrent_dropout=0.2,
                                   kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0,stddev=.5),
                                   bias_initializer=initializers.Zeros(),
                                   return_sequences = True))
    
    # 1st hidden layer
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=50,
                                   dropout=0.01,
                                   recurrent_dropout=0.2,
                                   kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0,stddev=.5),
                                   bias_initializer=initializers.Zeros(),
                                   return_sequences = True))
    
    # 2nd hidder layer
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=50,
                                   dropout=0.01,
                                   recurrent_dropout=0.2,
                                   kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0,stddev=.5),
                                   bias_initializer=initializers.Zeros(),
                                   return_sequences = False))
    
    # output layer
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3))
    
    model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='nadam',metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(x_data[train], y_data[train],
              verbose=2,
              batch_size=None,
              epochs=10,
              validation_data=(x_data[validation], y_data[validation])
              #callbacks=early_stop
              )
    
    prediction = model.predict(x_data[validation])
    y_validation = y_data[validation]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LSTM layers need input in 3 dimensions:

```
(n_samples, time_steps, features)
```

You passed data with this format:

```
(n_samples, features)
```

Since you don't have a function to create time steps, the easiest solution would be to change your input to shape:

```
(40101, 1, 3)
```

Bogus data:

```
x_data = np.random.rand(40101, 1, 3)
y_data = np.random.rand(40101, 3)
```

Also, you shouldn't pass the number of samples in the `input_shape` argument of a Keras layer. Just use this:

```
input_shape=(1, 3)
```

So here is the corrected code (with bogus data):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import initializers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

x_data = np.random.rand(40101, 1, 3)
y_data = np.random.rand(40101, 3)

timeSeriesCrossValidation = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5)
for train, validation in timeSeriesCrossValidation.split(x_data, y_data):
    # create model
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

    # input layer
    model.add(LSTM(units=5,
                   input_shape=(1, 3),
                   dropout=0.01,
                   recurrent_dropout=0.2,
                   kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0, stddev=.5),
                   bias_initializer=initializers.Zeros(),
                   return_sequences=True))

    # 1st hidden layer
    model.add(LSTM(units=5,
                   dropout=0.01,
                   recurrent_dropout=0.2,
                   kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0, stddev=.5),
                   bias_initializer=initializers.Zeros(),
                   return_sequences=True))

    # 2nd hidder layer
    model.add(LSTM(units=50,
                   dropout=0.01,
                   recurrent_dropout=0.2,
                   kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0, stddev=.5),
                   bias_initializer=initializers.Zeros(),
                   return_sequences=False))

    # output layer
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3))

    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='nadam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(x_data[train], y_data[train],
              verbose=2,
              batch_size=None,
              epochs=1,
              validation_data=(x_data[validation], y_data[validation])
              # callbacks=early_stop
              )

    prediction = model.predict(x_data[validation])
    y_validation = y_data[validation]
```

If you want a function to create time steps, use this:

```
def multivariate_data(dataset, target, start_index, end_index, history_size,
                      target_size, step, single_step=False):
  data = []
  labels = []

  start_index = start_index + history_size
  if end_index is None:
    end_index = len(dataset) - target_size

  for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    indices = range(i-history_size, i, step)
    data.append(dataset[indices])

    if single_step:
      labels.append(target[i+target_size])
    else:
      labels.append(target[i:i+target_size])

  return np.array(data), np.array(labels)
```

It will give you the right shape, e.g.:

```
multivariate_data(dataset=np.random.rand(40101, 3), 
                  target=np.random.rand(40101, 3), 
                  0, len(x_data), 5, 0, 1, True)[0].shape
```

```
(40096, 5, 3)
```

You lost 5 data points because at the beginning you can't look 5 steps back in the past.

Comment: Nicolas Gervais, thank you so much for your feedback. It's already running, even though I'm still not 100% sure that this is the right implementation of a NARX NN. One thing more I'd like to ask: you say LSTM layers need input in 3 dimensions, is it also valid for Dense layers?

Comment: Nicolas Gervais, can you please confirm that last bit of code in your response? You're using x_data twice as input for the multivariate_data function. Is that right? I'm asking because in the definition of the function you identified the first input as "dataset" and the second as "target".

Comment: Dense layers can take 2D input. And you're right about `dataset` and `target`, even though it doesn't matter because it's random data. I changed it.